# Subquery returned more than 1 value - Update JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an update with a JOIN in it, SQL Server 2012. I just need to copy data from ScheduledStatusChange.Reason to Account.CancellationReason. There are 7 ScheduledStatusChange records that have 2 records for each matching Acccount record (making 14 records total, instead of 7).

So when I try to do the update below, I get this error message: "Subquery returned more than 1 value." Here's the update:

```
update gym.account
set CancellationReason = left(ltrim(rtrim(s.Reason)),50)
from gym.scheduledstatuschange s
join gym.account a
on s.AccountID = a.AccountID
where s.Applied = 1
and s.StartStatusID = 2
and a.membershipstatusid = 2
and isnull(ltrim(rtrim(a.CancellationReason)),'') = ''
and isnull(ltrim(rtrim(s.Reason)),'') <> ''
and s.scheduledstatuschangeid not in (5169,8370,6669,4617,6707,4727,5048)
```

Notice the last line. I'm filtering out the 7 records that bring duplicates, but I still get the same error. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: Your query has not subqueries.  The error that you mention doesn't arise when more than one row matches the `update`.  In that case, the results are simply arbitrary.

Comment: Gordon, so what is your solution?

Comment: Maybe a trigger that has a problem?

Comment: My suspicion is that the query that is generating the error is not the query you think you are running.

Comment: You are both right, there was a trigger interfering. After dropping the trigger, everything works. Thanks guys!

Comment: You may wish to go back and fix your trigger before you re enable it.